# O-notation, O(∞) = O(1)?

Tags: infinity, big-o

So a quick thought; Could one argue that O(∞) is actually O(1)?

- I mean it isn't depend on input size?
- So in some way its, constant, even though it infinity.

Or is the only 'correct' way to express it O(∞)?

Comment: Interesting. Never heard of O(\infty)

Comment: [Bogosort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort) is this, according to Wiki.

Comment: @delnan: every operating system should be designed to run forever, and so should many GUIs.

Comment: @larsman: What gives? I know that and never claimed otherwise. I was merely providing a link for Giacomo and potentially others that would like an example of `O(infinity)`.

Comment: @delnan: I wasn't pointing out a mistake. I was just giving examples of more useful programs :)

Answer (score 12):

Infinity is not a number, or at least not a [real number](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Real_number), so the expression is malformed. The correct way to express this is to simply state that a program doesn't terminate. Note: *program*, not *algorithm*, as an algorithm is guaranteed to terminate.

(If you wanted, you might be able to define big-O notation on transfinite numbers. I'm not sure if that would be of any use, though.)

Comment: Your point is ofcourse valid, it's outside the definition in a way, but using o(infinity) as the runninng time of a non terminating program is just a, sometimes used, convention

Comment: @Peter: I've never seen it. I'd find it confusing and I believe I'm not the only one :)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort, as pointed out, but aside I agree, I'm not a fan of it either.

Comment: @Peter: ah, I hadn't spotted the infobox. (Strange: in Prolog programming, bogosort is the name for the one-liner that sorts by walking through all permutations, `sort(Lst,Srt) :- permutation(Lst,Srt), sorted(Srt).`, which runs in O(n!).)

Comment: Yes, but sorting by coincidence can of course be much worse than all permutations, never ending is the WCS, not the average.  Same name for different things apparantly; interesting info though.

Answer (score 7):

Your argument is not quite correct.

Big O notation disregards constant multiples; there's no difference between `O(1)` and `O(42)`, or between `O(log(n))` and `O(3π log(n))` .

Standard convention is to not use any constant multiples.

However, `O(∞)` would mean an “algorithm” that *never* terminates, as opposed to `O(1)` which will terminate at some point.

Comment: An "algorithm that never terminates" is formally not an algorithm (no matter how useful it is).

Comment: What about `strlen` in C when it's not given a NUL-terminated string, there is infinite memory and no zeros in that memory? Purely hypothetical, but does that count?

Answer (score 3):

To answer the question :

> O-notation, O(∞) = O(1)?

**No**

The main difference is that O(1) will end at some point, while  O(∞) never ends.

They both don't include a variable, but have both different meanings :

`O(1)` (or O(121) or O(whatever but not infinity) : independendent of the functions arguments, but ending

`O(∞)` : independendent of the functions arguments, and non ending

As pointed out in another answer, infinity isn't really in the domain of the big-O notation, but the simple 'no' than remains of course, O(1) and O(∞) are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

Big-Oh is a measure of how something the resources required scales as N increases. O(5 hours) and O(5 seconds) are both O(1) since no extra resources are needed as N increases.