# Time complexity infinite recursion

Tags: python, recursion, time

I have a quick question regarding asymptotic time complexity. What's the time complexity (big O) of this function below? From what I understand, it seems like it's infinite recursion and as such, what would be the big O notation for that?

```
def asymptoticTest (int1, int2):
  if int1 < int2:
    asymptoticTest(int1 + 1, int2)
  elif int1 > int2:
    asymptoticTest(int1 - 1, int2)
  else:
    asymptoticTest(int2, int1)
```

Comment: O(infinity)? Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5627390/o-notation-o%E2%88%9E-o1

Comment: Probably better answered on CS Stackexchange, e.g. http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/56556/complexity-analysis-of-an-unsolvable-algorithmic-problem

Answer (score 2):

It takes a constant amount of time (infinity) based on the input, so I'd call this O(1). O(1) doesn't mean "fast", it just means constant.